# How to use fadeIn with css property change jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fadein

**HTML :**

```
<input id ="input"/>
<div id="box"></div>
```

**CSS :**

```
#box{
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px; 
}
```

**JS :**

```
$('#input').on('focus',function(){
    $("#box").css('background', 'linear-gradient(red, transparent)')
})
```

However I want it to fade in so I tried this:

```
$("#box").css('background', 'linear-gradient(red, transparent)').fadeIn(1500);
```

And also this

```
$('#input').on('focus',function(){
  $("#box").fadeIn(1500, function(){
    $("#box").css('background', 'linear-gradient(red, transparent)');
  });
})
```

But both don't work. Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f99xjux7/1/)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fadeIn()` works on hidden elements so you could hide your `box` using `hide()` then fadein will works :

```
$('#input').on('focus',function(){
  $("#box").hide().css('background', 'linear-gradient(red, transparent)').fadeIn(1500);
})
```

Hope this helps.

---

Answer (score 3):

Try to set `display` property as `none` initially,

JS:

```
$('#input').on('focus',function(){
  $("#box").css('background', 'linear-gradient(red, transparent)').fadeIn(1500);
});
```

CSS:

```
#box{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display:none;
}
```

Technically, `fadeIn()` will not animate(fade in) an element which is already visible. Also we should not confuse `display` property with `visible` property. Even if `visible` property is set with `hidden` fadeIn will not work. `display : none` is the valid one for `.fadeIn()`

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/f99xjux7/2/)